# Pivot tables - Consildating payments into one

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2016

I'm new to this forum. I need some help with pivot tables:

**Question:**
I'm trying to consolidate payments Ids together, specifically payments which have the same ID but different payments needs to be merged and totalled into one row rather then having multiple sub totals. I done a head-start with pivot tables.

**Example:**
For example payment ID 9 could have 3 separate payments with the amount of £4,£5,£7. I need to combine them into one total of £16, rather three separate payments.

**Problem:**
When I do a pivot table from each table (C1 and C2) separately it works perfectly. But I don't know how to match pay ids which consist on both to be to do a comparison.

**Problem 2:** 
The alternative I tried, using the data range of both tables. However payment ID from the second table appears to be in different format to payments from the first table. It has the "-" icon by it allowing you to expand or collapse that ID.

**Example of the pivot table formatting issue:**

[pivot table example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdWo9.png)

Could some one please help me out.

Comment: include a small sample of data and demonstrate expected outcome. You can use [markdown table generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) to to copy paste a table from Excel to markdown to paste in your question via [edit]. Then select the table and press Ctrl + K.

Comment: @QHarr thank you for your response. I have my example of data with that link please see the image. But I don't know what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Power Query to bring both sets of data into one table in a Power Pivot data model.
Base your Pivot Table on the table in the data model.